# How do I update dropdown options after input data change

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

I have dropdown list where options are filling with values inside `js` code. After click on submit button, I want my dropdown to be changed for updated values, but it will just add new values to already existed values.

**My idea** was in deleting all options before they are creating, so options with new values will be added from a scratch.

So I tried to receive the `length` of datalist, but something like `var x = document.getElementById("browsers").options.length;` from **w3schools** doesn't work.

In addition, I tried to receive all options with setting className for option and then get all options with `const options = document.getElementsByClassName('datalist-option')` and with this try I received all options, but then I can't iterate through them to do the following way:

```
const options = document.getElementsByClassName('datalist-option')

options.forEach(option => option.value = '')
```

which returns me **error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: options.forEach is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

**Code:**

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input')
const datalist = document.querySelector('#datalist')
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button')

const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

values.forEach(value => {
      const option = document.createElement('option')
      option.value = value
      datalist.appendChild(option)
})

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      values.splice(0, 5)

      values.forEach(value => {
            const option = document.createElement('option')
            option.value = value
            datalist.appendChild(option)
      })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="./test.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" list="datalist" id="input">
      <datalist id="datalist"></datalist>

      <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this question wasn't published just me to answer it, but actually I've found a solution.

I iterated through datalist children which returns HTMLCollection

```
for (let option of datalist.children)
            option.value = ''
```

And now code works as it has to

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input')
const datalist = document.querySelector('#datalist')
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button')

const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

values.forEach(value => {
      const option = document.createElement('option')
      option.value = value
      option.id = 'datalist-option'
      datalist.appendChild(option)
})

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      values.splice(0, 5)

      for (let option of datalist.children)
            option.value = ''

      values.forEach(value => {
            const option = document.createElement('option')
            option.value = value
            datalist.appendChild(option)
      })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="./test.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" list="datalist" id="input">
      <datalist id="datalist"></datalist>

      <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```